# points on elliptical curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

verify that both (2,6) and (0,7) satisfy y^2≡ x^3 + 4x + 20 (mod 29). we need to find whether these points satisfy the given curve .i am not sure exactly as how to proceed with the given problem. any help would be appreciated. 
Thank-You.

Comment: The definition is that $y^2-x^3-4x-20$ is divisible by $29$. So, just put $x=2$ and $y=6$, compute and try to divide by $29$. Do the same with $x=0$ and $y=7$.

Answer (score 0):

$(2,6)$ means $x = 2, y = 6$. Similarly, $(0, 7)$ means $x = 0$ and $y = 7$.

Therefore, you can just check if $$6^2 \equiv 2^3 + 4 \cdot 2 + 20 \pmod {29}$$ and $$7^2 \equiv 0^3 + 4 \cdot 0 + 20 \pmod {29}$$

are true.